# Keras OCR is not working on a local machine

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, ocr, tensorflow2.0

I have an image detection algorithm,which crops only the needed portion of the image from camera video,and then feeds it to the Keras OCR. However, error as in an image attached shows up when I add this code:`pipeline=keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()`

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I've tried to test Keras OCR's standard model as in the documentation, but the the same error pops up. I don't use GPU boost,so I assume that it's not related to the device drivers

How can I use Keras OCR on my local machine?

Comment: Please [do not post screenshots of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8471799). 
Does the file `D:\repos\tensorflow-yolov4-tflife` exist?

Comment: D:\repos\tensorflow-yolov4-tflite directory exists and contains my image detection program. About screenshots:How can I describe the problem,if there are several lines of errors popping up?I don't think that copying and pasting as a text is a good representation of the error

Answer (score 0):

Well,I launched the same program on Google Colab without using graphical acceleration,and it has shown the same error

The thing is that even if CUDA drivers installed,dll files were abscent. So,the problem here is in turning on the graphical acceleration